# Crash when accessing Object properties after decoding from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization

I have decodes JSON value into object. The object looks as expected, but when I try to access it's property.

[image]

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JSON, options: [])
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let doctor = try! decoder.decode(Doctor.self, from: jsonData)
let txt = "\(doctor.title). \(doctor.firstName) \(doctor.lastName)" // Runtime crash: (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40))
```

> Runtime crash: (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40))

**Class Person:**

```
import UIKit

class Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let imageURL: URL

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case imageURL = "profileImgPath"
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, imageURL:URL) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }
}
```

**Class Doctor:**

```
import UIKit

class Doctor: Person {
    var title: String


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, imageURL:URL, title: String) {
        self.title = title
        super.init(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, imageURL: imageURL)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

}
```

Comment: are `firstName` and `lastName` computed properties in `Doctor`? can you show `Doctor` class?

Comment: I guess that if you wont use `try!` and actually catch the exception, you'll probably get more details, did you implement `Codable` on at Doctor?

Comment: Is `Doctor` a subclass of `Person`?

Comment: @Kamran I've updated the question

Comment: @DanielKrom I've updated the question

Comment: @Chris I've updated the question

Comment: @Luda I added an answer, can you check now.

Comment: @Luda, thank you for posting more information, again, I'd go with instead of `try! decoder.decode(Doctor.self, from: json)` to `do { try ..} catch{..}` and see what error goes, if you `try!` and it fails, the instance is invalid and cause these crash exceptions

Comment: I think it needs an `init(from decoder:)` method in the Person class. Edit: I see Kamran has done that in their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i tried your code, it produced the same error and upon investigation, i found that this is an issue in `Swift 4.1`. You can check below,

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7090

Possible solution for now could be a slight rearrangement as below,

Remove `Codable` conformance from base class i.e `Person` but you can still decode the base class members by keeping the `init` method with `docoder` to be called from the child classes. Child classes will conform to `Codable` now.

```
class Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let imageURL: URL

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case imageURL = "profileImgPath"
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, imageURL:URL) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        self.lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        self.imageURL = try values.decode(URL.self, forKey: .imageURL)
    }
}

class Doctor: Person, Codable {
    var title: String


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, imageURL:URL, title: String) {
        self.title = title
        super.init(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, imageURL: imageURL)
    }

    required override init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.title = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }  
}
```

Now, if you have the following json, it will work as intended.

```
let json = """
{
  "title":"SomeTitle",
  "firstName": "SomeFirstName",
  "lastName": "SomeLastName",
  "profileImgPath": "urlPath"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let doctor = try! decoder.decode(Doctor.self, from: json)
print(doctor.firstName)
print(doctor.lastName)
print(doctor.title)
```

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: the base class had no init from decoder.. the compiler should have caught that and screamed I admit.. but it is logical too...