# Crashing on subclass properties after JSON serialisation

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I have the weirdest problem. After performing JSON serialisation and creating an object, the code crashes when trying to access any properties of the subclass. When I try to access properties of the superclass of the object they are printed properly.

Here is the class:

```
import UIKit

class Patient: Person {
    var approved: Bool
    var doctorId: Int

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case approved
        case doctorId
    }

    init(id: String, name: String, lastName: String, phoneNumber: String, email: String, imageURL:URL, approved:Bool, doctorId:Int) {
        self.approved = approved
        self.doctorId = doctorId
        super.init(id: id, firstName: name, lastName: lastName, imageURL: imageURL)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.approved  = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .approved)
        self.doctorId = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .doctorId)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(type(of: self)) - (\(self.firstName), \(self.lastName))" //superclass properties 
    }
}

struct PatientsList : Codable {
    let patients: [Patient]
}
```

Person class:

```
class Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let imageURL: URL?
    let id: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case imageURL = "profileImgPath"
        case id = "_id"
    }

    init(id: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, imageURL:URL) {
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.imageURL = imageURL
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        self.lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        self.imageURL = try values.decodeIfPresent(URL.self, forKey: .imageURL)
    }
}
```

This is how I perform serialisation:

```
do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JSON, options: [])
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let patientList = try! decoder.decode(PatientsList.self, from: jsonData)
                    completionBlock(.success(patientList.patients))
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
```

Here are 
    //in console: po(patient.approved) prints false 
    //in console: expression dump(patient)

> ▿ iHeal.Patient #0   ▿ super: iHeal.Person
>
> ```
> firstName: "Sarah"
>
> lastName: "Connor"
>
> imageURL: nil
>
> id: "5b367491052aaca6489e4805"
> ```
>
> birthDate: "1980-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"
>
> approved: false
>
> doctorId: 12

```
print(patient.approved) //crash
print(patient.doctorId) // if I comment out previous line, this one crashes
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x200000002)

Another strange thing I can mention: description is not called on Patient

```
print(patient) // prints plain: <Patient: 0x608000141c30>
```

The Json:

```
{
    "patients": [
        {
            "approved": false,
            "_id": "5b367491052aaca6489e4805",
            "birthDate": "1980-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "doctorId": 12,
            "firstName": "Sarah",
            "lastName": "Connor"
        },
        {
            "approved": false,
            "drains": [],
            "_id": "5b3674e5052aaca6489e66b3",
            "__v": 0,
            "birthDate": "1980-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "doctorId": 12,
            "firstName": "Sarah",
            "lastName": "Connor"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you share the `json` response? And how you are initializing this object?

Comment: @Luda, What is person class ?

Comment: Hi @Kamran, I've updated the question (it is a bit different that I though initially)

Comment: Hi @SagarChauhan, I've updated the question (it is a bit different that I though initially)

Comment: @Luda It looks like the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004441. Can you try that way.

Comment: Wow! I am such an idiot. How could I have missed it? I had the same error a week ago and you've answered me already. I am giving you extra points on the other thread via bounty. You are awesome!

Comment: The bounty is set. I can give it in 24 hours. In the mean time you can answer the same here. I will check it as correct as this is FINALY WORKING!!! (again :-/ )

Comment: @Luda Glad it helped. Bounty is enough to not answer here :)

Comment: Answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004441/crash-when-accessing-object-properties-after-decoding-from-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of: [Crash when accessing Object properties after decoding from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004441/crash-when-accessing-object-properties-after-decoding-from-json)

Removed `Codable` conformance from base class i.e Person but you can still decode the base class members by keeping the init method with docoder to be called from the child classes. Child classes will conform to Codable now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the similar issue, it's actually nil but when you print it in console it returns false. Try adding a breakpoint before `print(patient.approved)` and type in console `expression patient.approved = false` and see if that crashes (after you continue from that brakepoint). If not then you know what's the problem.

Comment: Still crashes :(

Comment: I've added the JSON in the question

Comment: Try typing this in console in the same breakpoint so see whats going on. `expression dump(patient)` How are you parsing that JSON and initializing the object patient?

Comment: Hi @Tuc3k, I've updated the question (it is a bit different that I though initially)

Comment: expression dump(patient)
▿ iHeal.Patient #0
  ▿ super: iHeal.Person
    - firstName: "Sarah"
    - lastName: "Connor"
    - imageURL: nil
    - id: "5b367491052aaca6489e4805"
  - birthDate: "1980-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  - approved: false
  - doctorId: 12

Answer (score 0):

You can try with if let condition to prevent your app from crash by using following code:

```
if let isApproved = patient.approved {
    print(isApproved)
}
```

This code will check nil condition for `approved` property, It will check if property not nil then assign value to `isApproved` parameter else condition will goes out and code not execute inside `if block`.

This will better solution to prevent crash issue.

Comment: `approved` is not an `optional` variable so this code will create a compiler error.

Comment: I get: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'

Comment: Added the JSON in the question

Comment: Hi @Sagar Chauhan, I've updated the question (it is a bit different that I though initially)

Answer (score 0):

You should post your JSON and how you parse it. A minimal example as in

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
{
    "doctorId": 12345,
    "approved": false
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Patient : Codable {
    var approved: Bool
    var doctorId: Int
}

do {
    let patient = try JSONDecoder().decode(Patient.self, from:jsonData)
    print(patient)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

will provide you with trouble free parsing of your booleans as long as you follow JSON conventions. You will have to provide the above information in order for answers to be more concrete.

### Update

Unfortunately it is still not easy to reproduce your error. I have tried

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
{
    "patients": [
        {
            "approved": false,
            "drains": [],
            "_id": "5b367491052aaca6489e4805",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5b36747d28c1c608808274ce",
                "email": "17@iheal.com"
            },
            "__v": 0,
            "birthDate": "1980-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "doctorId": 12,
            "firstName": "Sarah",
            "lastName": "Connor",
            "phoneNum": "123"
        },
        {
            "approved": false,
            "drains": [],
            "_id": "5b3674e5052aaca6489e66b3",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5b3674e428c1c608808274cf",
                "email": "18@iheal.com"
            },
            "__v": 0,
            "birthDate": "1980-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "doctorId": 12,
            "firstName": "Sarah",
            "lastName": "Connor",
            "phoneNum": "123"
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Patient : Codable {
    var approved: Bool
    var doctorId: Int
}

struct PatientList: Codable{
    let patients: [Patient]
}

do {
    let patients = try JSONDecoder().decode(PatientList.self, from:jsonData)
    print(patients)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

but this still does not have any problem at all. From what I can see I would have to *guess* what your `Person`-class looks like, but it will most probably be `Codable`. Frankly speaking I do have experience with inheriting `Codable` types, but your approach does not look unreasonable. This *is* however difficult to judge if your `Person` class is not part of your question (and neither is your JSON-parsing in its current form). I am afraid you will have to post these things in order to get a meaningful response.

Comment: I've added the JSON in the question

Comment: Hi @Patro, I've updated the question (it is a bit different that I though initially)